# Getting Count Result With Multiple Conditions

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-orm

I have models named `Class, StudentList, Child, TakingQuiz and TakingQuizAnswer`. Students can take exams. In this case, when they start the exam, data is added to the 'TakingQuiz' table. With each new answer, the answers are also recorded in the `TakingQuizAnswer` table.

The result I want to reach -> The question with the most mistakes in the exams solved by the students in a class.
I tried to use `Count` for this. I'm filtering `answer_is_correct` to `False` but that is insufficient. I also need to filter this data for the `question` column. So I need to get rows where both `question` and `answer_is_correct = False` columns are the same and return the first few most repetitive data as results.

I always get a general result in my experiments. I can't include rows where the `question` column is the same. How can I access the questions with the most mistakes in exams solved by students studying in a class?

**Serializer**

```
class ClassSerializerReport(ModelSerializer):
    instructor = InstructorSerializerReport(source="instructor.user")
    students = StudenListSerializerReport(many=True,
                                          source="student_list_class")
    max_incorrect_question = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    class Meta:
        model = Class
        exclude = [
            "created_at",
            "updated_at",
            "school",
        ]

    def get_max_incorrect_question(self, obj):
        data = Class.objects.filter(id = obj.id).values('student_list_class__child__child_taking_quiz__taking_quizes').annotate(res = Count('student_list_class__child__child_taking_quiz__taking_quizes__question', filter = Q(student_list_class__child__child_taking_quiz__taking_quizes__answer_is_correct = False)))
        print(data)
        return {"question_id" : "I couldn't access that result yet."}
```

**Related Models**

```
class Class(AbstractSchoolBaseModel):
    school = models.ForeignKey(
        "school.School",
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name="classes_school",
        )
    instructor = models.ForeignKey(
        "account.InstructorProfile",
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name="instructors_school",
        )
    name = models.CharField(
        max_length=50,
        )
    grade = models.IntegerField(
        )

class StudentList(AbstractSchoolBaseModel):
    school_class = models.ForeignKey(
        "school.Class",
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name="student_list_class",
    )
    child = models.ForeignKey(
        "account.ChildProfile",
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name="student_list_children",
        )

class ChildProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        primary_key=True,
        related_name="user_child")
    city = models.ForeignKey(
        "country.City",
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        related_name="city_child_profiles")
    hobbies = models.CharField(
        max_length=500,
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        )


class TakingQuiz(AbstractQuizBaseModel):
        quiz = models.ForeignKey("quiz.Quiz", on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, related_name="quiz_taking_quiz")
        child = models.ForeignKey("account.ChildProfile", on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name = "child_taking_quiz")
        title = models.CharField(max_length=150, editable=False, default="-")
        total_point = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)


class TakingQuizAnswer(AbstractQuizBaseModel):
    taking_quiz = models.ForeignKey("quiz.TakingQuiz", on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="taking_quizes")
    question = models.ForeignKey("quiz.Question", on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, related_name="question_taking_quiz"e)
    answer = models.ForeignKey("quiz.Answer", on_delete= models.DO_NOTHING, related_name="answer_taking_quiz")
    taking_quiz_title = models.TextField(editable=False, null=True, blank=True)
    question_text = models.TextField(editable=False, null=True, blank=True)
    question_topic_content = models.TextField(editable=False, null=True, blank=True)
    answer_text = models.TextField(editable=False, null=True, blank=True)
    answer_is_correct = models.BooleanField(editable=False, null=True, blank=True)


class Quiz(AbstractQuizBaseModel):
    ENABLED_CHOICES = (
        (True, _("Active")),
        (False, _("Not Active")),
    )
    
    book = models.ForeignKey("book.Book", on_delete= models.CASCADE, related_name="book_quiz")
    title = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    enabled = models.BooleanField(choices=ENABLED_CHOICES, default=False)


class Question(AbstractQuizBaseModel):
    quiz = models.ForeignKey("quiz.Quiz", on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, related_name="question_quiz")
    question = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    topic = models.CharField(max_length=500)

class Answer(AbstractQuizBaseModel):
    IS_CORRECT_CHOICES = (
        (True, _("Correct Answer")),
        (False, _("Wrong Answer"))
    )

    question = models.ForeignKey("quiz.Question", on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name = "question_answer")
    answer = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    is_correct = models.BooleanField(choices=IS_CORRECT_CHOICES, default=False)
```

Comment: Where is your `Question` model?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I forgot it, I'm adding it right now.